# ¿Cómo consumir bases de datos con un orm?

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, orm, nestjs, typeorm

Se me ha pedido realizar una api para unas aplicaciones (estoy usando nestjs, typeorm, y postgresql para ello), la duda que me surgió, fue basado en que se me proporcionó un diagrama ER y una conexión a una bd que ya tiene tablas, de las cuales tengo que crear relaciones nuevas (estas tablas que ya existen no las puedo modificar, solo referenciar y usar para SELECT).

Entonces mi duda es, como logro hacer que en mis entidades se pueda hacer uso de estas tablas (realizar relaciones), existentes, evitando que aparezcan en las migraciones generadas para evitar cambios en las tablas ya existentes.

Hasta el momento he creado las entidades de las tablas que ya existen, sin embargo lo he hecho para ir haciendo pruebas con la aplicación, se que debo eliminarlas al conectarla con la bd de producción.